# Trying to get the first item in a list within a panda dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am a newbie to Python and Pandas and am trying to resolve an issue.

I have a pandas dataframe which contains a column, where the column data is a string, with values separated by a hyphen,

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['item 1 - item 2 - item 3'],['item 4 - item 5 - item 6 '],['item 
 7 - item 8'],['item 9']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Item'])

print(df)
```

Results to this:

```
                        Item
0   item 1 - item 2 - item 3
1  item 4 - item 5 - item 6 
2            item 7 - item 8
3                     item 9
```

I need to split the item rows to a list, which I can do with

```
df['Item'].str.split('-')
```

which resolves to

```
0     [item 1 ,  item 2 ,  item 3]
1    [item 4 ,  item 5 ,  item 6 ]
2               [item 7 ,  item 8]
3                         [item 9]
```

I need to get the first item in each row, so item 1 , item 4, item 7 , item 9
and hopefully strip out leading and trailing blank characters with the strip() method

Comment: `df['Item'].str.split('-').str[0].str.strip()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html), get first value of lists by indexing and last call [`Series.str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html):

```
s = df['Item'].str.split('-').str[0].str.strip()
print (s)
0    item 1
1    item 4
2    item 7
3    item 9
Name: Item, dtype: object
```

Comment: @MikeTunstall - Working like you need?

Comment: Yes thanks, also improves my knowledge of what can be done in Python, Pandas